# Web Service Namespace

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I am having problems with my webservice namespace. It works fine on my computer, but when i upload it to the team foundation server, it does not work for anybody else.

My code in the webservice (located in the 'Sentry.SAID' namespace in its own app:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Sentry.SAID.Core
Imports Sentry.SAID.Web

<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://localhost")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Powerbeatws
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
```

XML file in the 'Sentry.SAID.Web' app in the 'Sentry.SAID'namespace

```
        <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="PowerbeatwsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="11000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="11000000"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:62862/Powerbeatws.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="PowerbeatwsSoap" contract="PowerbeatSR.PowerbeatwsSoap"
       name="PowerbeatwsSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If i change the endpoint address to localhost/Powerbeatws.asmx, it throws an error. Any idea's how I can get this to work on seperate computers using localhost?

Currently to get it to work on any other computers, a new service reference must be added.

Comment: Assuming they are running your service on their local machine on port 62862, it should work I would think...perhaps their service port number hosting the service is different?

Comment: The service port number changes for each machine.

Comment: The `http://localhost` in the namespace has nothing to do with the `http://localhost:62862` in the config file. They are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

With Web Services we have to keep in mind there are 2 entities involved, the service being hosted and the client consuming it.

If both are to use localhost in their bindings, they must assume the same port number OR the persons downloading your code from TFS have to change the endpoint binding from localhost:62862 to whichever port the service is running on their machine.

You can alternatively create a specific hosting address either through configuration on the web service or through code where a well known port is used by everyone e.g. 51000. Change the endpoint bindings to localhost:51000 and make sure the service host is listening on port 51000 and it should work fine.

I believe the problem to be the team isn't using the same port numbers on their localhosts, so the bindings do not work. It works on your machine because you are hosting the service on port 62862.

Could be wrong though. Not sure what the exception is they are seeing but this isn't an uncommon problem to have when sharing web service code.